gRPC 1.65.2 library size too big
I built gRPC libraries for C++ from source code on Linux Redhat 8.10 with gcc 13. The size of resulted libgrpc.a is close to 400M, while our old libgrpc.a from 1.38 (built on Redhat 7 with gcc 9) is only 9M.
Turning off the support for other languages such PHP, Objectc, Node, C# doesn't help.
Is it expected? is there any way to cut down the library size?
Thanks,
Frank
